# Client closed connection before receiving entire response AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

unable to download file 
getting this error "Client closed connection before receiving entire response"
the file which i am trying to download is just 266KB

```
     for (NSString *downloadURL in arr) {
   // NSString *downloadURL = [d objectForKey:@"url"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"URL for downloading : %@",downloadURL);
        NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *downloadedZipPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:TEMP_DICTIONARY];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURL]];
       // [request addValue:@"bytes=x-" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
       // [request setTimeoutInterval:20];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:downloadedZipPath append:NO];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [operation start];
    });
```

tried to increase api request time out but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have some error like this. But I think it is not the AF faults. When the thing's content-type you request is different from it's original content type this error will come out.
For Example:
When you request a mp4 file, the server should set the content-type to video/mpeg4, or you can change your request type from GET to POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to more time

```
[request setTimeoutInterval:20];
```